# Bash redirection in docker container failing when ran in ECS task on Amazon Linux 2 instances

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run an ECS task that contains 3 containers - postgres, redis, and an image from a private ECR repository. The custom image container definition has a command to wait until the postgres container can receive traffic via a bash command

```json
"command": [
    "/bin/bash",
    "-c",
    "while !</dev/tcp/postgres/5432; do echo \"Waiting for postgres database to start...\"; /bin/sleep 1; done; /bin/sh /app/start-server.sh;"
],
```

When I run this via `docker-compose` on my local machine through docker it works, but on the Amazon Linux 2 EC2 machine this is printed when the while loop runs:

> /bin/bash: line 1: postgres: Name or service not known
>
> /bin/bash: line 1: /dev/tcp/postgres/5432: Invalid argument

The postgres container runs without error and the last log from that container is

> database system is ready to accept connections

I am not sure if this is a docker network issue or an issue with amazon linux 2's bash not being compiled with `--enable-net-redirections` which I found explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241177)

Task Definition:

```json
{
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
                    "value": "metadeploy"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
                    "value": "<redacted>"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "<redacted>"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres:12.9",
            "mountPoints": [],
            "name": "postgres",
            "memory": 1024,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "metadeploy-postgres",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "mdp"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "redis:6.2",
            "name": "redis",
            "memory": 1024
        },
        {
        "command": [
            "/bin/bash",
            "-c",
            "while !</dev/tcp/postgres/5432; do echo \"Waiting for postgres database to start...\"; /bin/sleep 1; done; /bin/sh /app/start-server.sh;"
        ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                    "value": "config.settings.local"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DATABASE_URL",
                    "value": "<redacted-postgres-url>"
                },
                {
                    "name": "REDIS_URL",
                    "value": "redis://redis:6379"
                },
                {
                    "name": "REDIS_HOST",
                    "value": "redis"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "the private ecr image uri built from here https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/MetaDeploy",
            "links": [
                "redis"
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/app/node_modules",
                    "sourceVolume": "AppNode_Modules"
                }
            ],
            "name": "web",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 6006,
                    "hostPort": 6006
                }
            ],
            "memory": 1024,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "metadeploy-web",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "mdw"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "MetaDeploy",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/app/node_modules"
            },
            "name": "AppNode_Modules"
        }
    ]
}
```

The corresponding `docker-compose.yml` contains:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: metadeploy
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sample_db_password
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    image: postgres:12.9
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: |
      /bin/bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/postgres/5432; do echo "Waiting for postgres database to start..."; /bin/sleep 1; done; \
      /bin/sh /app/start-server.sh;'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8000:8000'
      # Storybook server
      - '6006:6006'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings.local
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:sample_db_password@postgres:5432/metadeploy
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules
```

Do I need to recompile bash to use `--enable-net-redirections`, and if so how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe try `while ! nc -z postgres 5432; do echo "Waiting for postgres database to start..."; /bin/sleep 1; done; /bin/sh /app/start-server.sh` instead - does that make a difference?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary That results in `/bin/bash: line 1: nc: command not found`

Comment: Are you sure the custom image is based on AL2?

Comment: The image was built on an M1 mac which had some issues of its own. I had to follow this guide https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-actually-deploy-docker-images-built-on-a-m1-macs-with-apple-silicon-a35e39318e97

I built the image by running `docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t dev-metadeploy .` Is there a different platform I should have targeted?

Comment: Unless you mean the Dockerfile then no it's based on ghcr.io/oddbird/pyjs:py3.9-node16, but I'm not sure why the host OS would pose a problem for the commands issued to the container.

Comment: Why not move all that script logic into your `start-server.sh` file instead of trying to do a bash script inline in the docker `command`?

Comment: Anyhow, PostgreSQL comes with a program that's built _specifically_ to wait for the database server to be started (and to check that it's not just available for connections but actually able to run queries)! Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: "Name or service not known", btw, reads very much like a name resolution problem more than the feature not being enabled. Is `getent hosts postgres` able to do a successful lookup at the same time that opening `/dev/tcp/postgres/5432` fails with that error?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the author of this app so I can't speak to the decision made, I'm just trying to run it in an ECS task. I think I'm just going to create my own ec2 instance and run docker-compose instead

Comment: Ehhh that's not entirely true. This is open source so I don't want to deviate too much because I would like to integrate updates from the upstream repository in the future. The repo doesn't come with ECS tasks which I have created so I am modifying it. Also, S/O now supports collectives which open S/O to more than just "developing software". Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Without bash's net redirection feature, your best bet is to use something like `nc` or `netcat` (if available) to determine if the port is open.  If those aren't available, it may be worth modifying your app logic to better handle database failure cases.

Alternately, a potential better approach would be:

1. Adding a [`healthcheck`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) to the `postgres` image.
2. Modifying the `web` service's [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) clause "long syntax" to add a dependency on `postgres` being `service_healthy` instead of the default `service_started`.

This approach has two key benefits:

1. The `postgres` image likely has the tools to detect if the database is up and running.
2. The `web` service no longer needs to manually check if the database is ready or not.

Comment: What's particularly notable here is that postgresql itself includes a `pg_isready` executable designed to do exactly what the OP intends (and better than this loop would, because `pg_isready` can distinguish between "accepting connections but not yet able to run queries successfully" and "fully open for business")